# How to return multiple rows of data in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ienumerable

Hi I am doing web api project. I have one get http verb and i want to return multiple rows of data. I am using angular in front end. I am trying as below.

```
public IEnumerable<NCT_Process_Settings> Get()
{
    NCT_Process_Settings obj = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process_Settings select c).AsEnumerable();
    return obj;
}
```

As i know my query returns collection and my object obj  is not capable of handling multiple rows of data. So is there any way i can handle this? Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: `IEnumerable<NCT_Process_Settings> obj =(from ....` (your query returns a collection, not a single object

Comment: Thank you. Please post answer. Worked...

Comment: You could also use `var obj = (from ...` which would infer the type

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this, its working fine

```
public static List<Student> items = new List<Student>();


        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudents()
        {
            if (items.Count() == 0)
            {
                items.Add(new Student { ID = 1, Name = "Ashish", City = "New Delhi", Course = "B.Tech" });
                items.Add(new Student { ID = 2, Name = "Nimit", City = "Noida", Course = "MCA" });
                items.Add(new Student { ID = 3, Name = "Prawah", City = "Dehradun", Course = "B.Tech" });
                items.Add(new Student { ID = 4, Name = "Sumit", City = "Nainital", Course = "MCA" });
            }

            return items;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
        [Route("api/test")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            List<table_name> obj = new List<table_name>();
            try
            {
                obj = db.table_name.AsNoTracking().ToList();

                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

then access this api with http://192.168.0.1/api/test

table_name can be a model

Answer (score 1):

You declare a variable which is a single object, but your trying to assign a collection of objects to it (the result of your query). Change the code to

```
IEnumerable<NCT_Process_Settings> obj = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process_Settings select c).AsEnumerable();
return obj;
```

or

```
var obj = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process_Settings select c).AsEnumerable();
return obj;
```

Comment: Thank you. If i get rows to var then  IEnumerable<NCT_Process_Settings> will it work? Sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: using `var` will work fine (internally, the compiler infers the type based on what your query returns so its the same as `IEnumerable<NCT_Process_Settings> `). And as a side note, you may  not need the `.AsEnumerable()` which makes it an in-memory set. You could just return `IQueryable<NCT_Process_Settings>` which might be more efficient depending on what you then do with that collection

Comment: Thank you. I understood and thank you for making me to understand the concept.